# Sometime my button is not working in my app

Tags: android, gps, android-button

I am checking GPS is enabled or not on the click of button, sometime GPS is enable that time also my button is not working. If i'm switching off the gps and again switch on the GPS manually then it's working.

How can i fix that one?

Here is my GPS code

```
/*
 * checking gps is available or not in android device.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean isGPSAvailable() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    boolean isGPSOn = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(
            contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!isGPSOn) {
        new DialogHelper(this, R.string.title_err_attention,
                R.string.msg_err_nogps, R.string.txt_settings,
                R.string.txt_exit, new DialogCallBack() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPositiveBtnClick() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPositiveBtnClick();
                        Intent settings = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(settings);
                        Home.this.finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onNegativeBtnClick() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onNegativeBtnClick();
                        Home.this.finish();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    return isGPSOn;
}
```

Comment: Do you have code> post it

Comment: Show is your logic how you make sure GPS is enabled in Code

Comment: I have posted my code @MD

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean like:
`isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

Answer (score 0):

I have made one method for checking GPS status . It might help you.

```
public static boolean isGpsAvailable(Context context) {
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean statusOfGPS = manager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return statusOfGPS;
        }
```